# Cant control drag elements using assistant editor

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I was playing around little in Xcode and I do not know what I have pressed but my assistant editor behaves really weird. I can not control drag elements to create a connection like you usually could do with e.g a button. I can drag it but when I release it nothing happens. There is no green plus sign that appears when you can make a connection. Here is a screenshot of how it looks like maybe if it helps..

Wasted about an hour trying to fix this. I wanna tear out my hair.
[image]

Comment: In the Interface Builder window can you try zooming in?

Comment: I finally am able to ask it: "have you tried turning it off and on again"? Srsly: have you tried quitting Xcode and restarting it? Would not be the first time that it got a hiccup while running

Comment: @Kevin not sure exactly where you want me to zoom in. If you click on the picture you can zoom once here in stack overflow

Comment: Yes, Tried that and restarting my whole mac @luk2302

Comment: I read somewhere and i think it has to do something with that extra window that i opened. It said somewhere that it could be in the wrong class or whatever. Not really sure @luk2302

Comment: In the second window of Xcode where you have your UIButton, zoom in by double clicking then try and drag from the button to the `InitialViewController.swift` window.

Comment: I solved it. I had not defined to which swift file the viewcontroller belonged to in the mainstoryboard. Thank you anyway guys ! @Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten to define what swift file the viewController was for in the main storyboard!